# Mobile ad install tracking - get campaign name and ad name

Tags: facebook, mobile, installation, tracking, ads

I want to be able to track an mobile ad install after a user has installed my app and registered in my system. I understand that I need to notify Facebook about it using the publishInstall (Android) for tracking the number of installs, however I couldn't find a way to get the campaign and ad names from Facebook per device, Is there a way to get the campaign and ad name/id from Facebook per device install?

Comment: Well, it is not possible to get this information from Facebook. Notice however that there are few companies which actually have access to this information...

Comment: Do you know which companies?